# How To View The Whole Project In Another Commit While Showing All The Other Commits

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout, git-log

I like this neat little feature in Intellij where I can do something like this:
[image]

As you can see in the picture, I reset HEAD to the commit that reads "revert .... own" where I can view the entire project structure at that commit. However, I still see all of the other commits above that, so at any time I can choose to see one commit above that at any time. For example, if I realized that I wanted to see "correctly used antlr" instead of the commit that I'm on right now, then I can just reset to that commit right away. Intellij shows where HEAD is as and where master is at at all times.

In the command line, however, I couldn't find this same behavior. Looking at other StackOverflow questions, I tried these two methods:

```
1. git checkout <commit_id>
2. git reset --hard <commit_id>
```

With the first method, `git checkout <commit_id>`, I don't get the same effect as what I intended. Here is what shows when I do a `git log`:

[image]

It shows the correct information (where HEAD is at, where master is at). However, I do `git checkout HEAD~1`. Then when I do `git log` I get:

[image]

In this picture, the only information given is where HEAD is at. I don't see any commits above that when I type git log.

The same thing happens when I use `git reset --hard`. I get reset to that commit, but `git log` doesn't show any commits above that.

What I want to happen is I can just surf the commits by resetting to that commit to view the entire project at that commit, then when I type `git log` it shows all the commits (even the most recent one), where HEAD is at, and where master is at. Then I can reset to any commit I choose, even the ones more recent than the current commit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a bit more research I got my answer. When doing the git log, the correct command is `git log --all`.